# $T: [0,1)\to [0,1), x\mapsto 10x-\lfloor 10x\rfloor$

Tags: elementary-functions

> > Consider $T: [0,1)\to [0,1), x\mapsto 10x-\lfloor 10x\rfloor$.

Is that the same as 
$$
10x (mod 1)?
$$
or in which sense is that multiplication with 10 mod 1?

Comment: It's true in general that $g(x)-[g(x)]$ is identically $g(x) \text{ mod } 1$. This is just because $x - [x] =x \text{ mod } 1$ (compose this with $g$).

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly the same.  It is also just move the decimal one position right and erase what comes to the left.

Comment: What is f.e. $T^{-1}([0.5,0.75))$? Is that $\bigcup_{k=0}^{9}[0.05,0.075]\pm k$?

Comment: No, $k$ is $0,0.1,0.2\dots0.9$ and no minus sign, so $[0.05,0.075)\cup [0.15,0.175)\dots \cup[0.95,0.975)$

Comment: Then my script is wrong? It says: $T^{-1}(B)=\left\{x\in [0,1): Tx\in B\right\}=\bigcup_{k=0}^{9}\frac{1}{10}B-k$.

Comment: Yes, it is wrong.  The domain of $T$ is given as $[0,1)$, so you can't add (for example) $5$.  Try applying $T$ to some of the points in my set, you can see how it works.  I think you lost parentheses around $B-k$-the $k$ should be divided by $10$, but the sign should be $+$.